# Add context menu in registry

Tags: windows, contextmenu, windows-shell

I've seen [an example at this address](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-open-with-notepad-to-the-context-menu-for-all-files/) on how to add context menus by just dropping a key to the registry (in the example, we add one link to Notepad.exe for each file type *).

The example works fine, instantly. However, I don't understand why I can't reproduce the same with "excel.exe %1" under .xla.

Here is a screen of what I tried, initially, "shell" folder seems to be missing for each extension. Since I couldnt get any effect with "shellex", I added it... I can't see my menu :

[image]

Please keep in mind I am a registry newbie :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are missing a level of indirection here. Normally, `.xla` will reference a certain file type, e.g. `xlafile` and the letter in turn will have `shell` and `shellex` subkeys referencing context menu handlers.

See:

- [Verbs and File Associations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776881.aspx)
- [Creating Shortcut Menu Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I see what you mean but I don't find the proper path... Initially shellex was right under .xla. Does that give us any clue ?

Comment: In .xla, I see "Excel.Addin" is tje value for the "default" key, then "application/vnd.ms-excel" is another value, for a second key named "Content Type". What does that tell me ?

Comment: So create `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Excel.Addin\shell\Close` key and populate it. You should see the new item "Close" under `.xla`'s context menu.